# Unexpected line in transparent border?

Tags: html, css

I have a button with a 1px transparent border. Hovewer, if you take a look at the example I provided, there is a darker line along  the left border. I'm not sure why this happens and how to fix it. I do need that border to be `1px solid transparent`. Thank you.

```css
*{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.container{
  width:100wh;
  height:100vh;
  text-align:center;
}

.card__link{
  max-width:200px;
  text-align:center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 3.5rem;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, hsl(236, 72%, 79%), hsl(237, 63%, 64%));
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  letter-spacing:1px;
}

.card__link:hover{
  border:1px solid hsl(237, 63%, 64%);
  color: hsl(237, 63%, 64%);
  background:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <a href="#" class="card__link">Learn More</a>
</div>
```

Comment: @Justinas yes, thank you! Care making an answer ?

Comment: No, just closing question as it's duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by using `box-shadow` to have an inner border.

```
box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px 1px hsl(237, 63%, 64%);
```

and remove

```
border: 0px solid transparent;
```

```css
*{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.container{
  width:100wh;
  height:100vh;
  text-align:center;
}

.card__link{
  max-width:200px;
  text-align:center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 3.5rem;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, hsl(236, 72%, 79%), hsl(237, 63%, 64%));
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  letter-spacing:1px;
}

.card__link:hover{
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px hsl(237, 63%, 64%);
  color: hsl(237, 63%, 64%);
  background:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <a href="#" class="card__link">Learn More</a>
</div>
```

Comment: But then on hover when there is border your element will flicker as it's width will increase by 2px (by 2 * border size)

Comment: i need it to be 1px to prevent content resizing on hover. If it's 0 when i hover and 1px is added content is resized

Comment: @Noob, Justinas updated.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the linear gradient. You use a transparent border so that it takes gradient color also. Give border-color white instead of transparent.

Try this:

```
border: 1px solid #ffffff;
```

Comment: White border is not same as transparent border. It will be seen if placed on colored background...

Comment: Yes, but it will work here that's why I gave the white border to the button. @Justinas

Answer (score -1):

there's a weird collision with the gradient background... you can do the same effect with `box-shadow`:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100wh;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
}

.card__link {
  max-width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 3.5rem;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, hsl(236, 72%, 79%), hsl(237, 63%, 64%));
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.card__link:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px hsl(237, 63%, 64%);
  color: hsl(237, 63%, 64%);
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#" class="card__link">Learn More</a>
</div>
```